# xampp phpmyadmin error #1142 when wamp is running

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, wamp

I have xampp installed on my pc, and yesterday I have installed wamp also. I have changed the **Listen 80** to **Listen 81** in **Apache2.2 httpd.conf** file of wampserver and the both localhost is running fine together. 
Thr problem is when the wampserver is running the xampp phpmyadmin is showing error -

> **#1142 - SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'pma_column_info'**

and when wampserver is off then the phpmyadmin in xampp is working properly.

Do you have any idea to run those two different mysql server at same time?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your MySQL port also. do you use any database management tool other than phpmyadmin? Check the port MySQL server is running

Comment: I have already checked that. I have changed the **port 3306** to 3307 or something like that in **my.cnf** file in wamp then I found the phpmyadmin wamp is showing the databases those are belonging to the xampp phpmyadmin. strange! still the problem not solved.